# Spring Boot MVC: secure path with diffrent client registration data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid

Using Spring Boot v2.7.11, Spring v5.3.27.

My application.yml configuration:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      provider:
        provider-example:
          ....
      registration:
        client1:
          client-id: c_id1
          client-secret: c_s1  
          ....
        client2:
          client-id: c_id2
          client-secret: c_s2
          ....
```

I would like to secure two main paths **/client1/**** and **/client2/**** with diffrent client registration data. Everytime when unauthenticated user hit one of **/client1/**** URL's, it shoud be redirected to authentication provider "provider-example" with **"client1"** registration data and when hit one of **/client2/**** URL's shoud be redirected to same authentication provider with **"client2"** registration data.

How can this be done?